# php output data from SQL in three columns with sorting

Tags: php, sql

Try to bring 2 values ​​(id, name) from the table table in three columns with sorting by columns, like this first column (1,2,3), the second column (4,5,6), third (7.8).

Get to do 3 columns and 2-output values, but was sorting the rows. Turned sorting by columns, but the second could not get value. Help solve the problem.

Сode:

```
$values = array();
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT id, name FROM table");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $values[] = $row['name'];
}

function array_chunk_vertical($input, $size, $preserve_keys = false, $size_is_horizontal = true)
{
    $chunks = array();

    if ($size_is_horizontal) {
        $chunk_count = ceil(count($input) / $size);
    } else {
        $chunk_count = $size;
    }

    for ($chunk_index = 0; $chunk_index < $chunk_count; $chunk_index++) {
        $chunks[] = array();
    }

    $chunk_index = 0;
    foreach ($input as $key => $value)
    {
        if ($preserve_keys) {
            $chunks[$chunk_index][$key] = $value;
        } else {
            $chunks[$chunk_index][] = $value;
        }

        if (++$chunk_index == $chunk_count) {
            $chunk_index = 0;
        }
    }

    return $chunks;
}

$rows = array_chunk_vertical($values, 3);

print "<table>\n";
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    print "<tr>\n";
    foreach ($row as $value) {
        print "<td>" . $value . "</td>\n";
    }
    print "</tr>\n";
}
print "</table>\n";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(If i understood ).Change:

```
//...
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  $values[] = array('name'=>$row['name'],'id'=>$row['id']);
}

//..
print "<table>\n";
 foreach ($rows as $row) {
   print "<tr>\n";
   foreach ($row as $item) {
     print "<td>" . $item['id'].' '.$item['name']."</td>\n";
   }
 print "</tr>\n";
}
print "</table>\n";
```